# javascript get arguments of invoked function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arguments

I want to get arguments of invoked function (method) in this javascript code:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function myFunc(method) {
    // I'm trying to     get method arguments in next line
    if (method.apply(null, arguments[0]) !== 'number') // it shows here: method.apply is not a function
        throw new Error('argument 1 must be a number');
    return method;
}

console.log(myFunc(add(1, 2)));
```

As you see myFunc has a function as a parameter, and I want to get this invoked function arguments. This is my try:

```
method.apply(null,arguments) // method.apply is not a function
```

or

```
 method.arguments // undefined
```

what I inertsted to get is [a,b] arguments in order to do some validation to them, but I'm getting Nan.

Comment: What values do you expect to get for `a` and `b` when calling `myFunc(add)` - there are no numbers in your code anywhere?

Comment: The [`apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) has two required parameters

Comment: I updates the post by calling myFunc(add(1,2)) so lets say add has two numbers as parameters

Comment: In that case, you are no longer passing a "method" to `myFunc` but just the number `3`, the result from the call `add(1, 2)`. You don't need to use `apply` or `arguments` any more, you just need `function myFunc(number) { console.log(number); }` for that to work

Comment: at the beginning of myFun, I want to do something like this


`if (typeof method.apply(null, arguments[0]) !== 'number') throw new Error('argument 1 must be a number');`

Comment: I need to pass a "method" to myFunc. the real project I'm working is more complicated, and I just trying to simplify what is the problem I'm facing: reaching "method" arguments @Bergi

Comment: You can either pass a function and then call it yourself with some arguments, or you can pass the result of a function call. You cannot pass an "invoked function" (what is that, a function which is currently in the process of being called?) and then figure out what arguments it has been invoked with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really messed up, but I think you are looking for something like

```js
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function myFunc(fn, args) {
    if (typeof args[0] !== 'number')
        throw new Error('first argument must be a number');
    return fn.apply(null, args);
}

console.log(myFunc(add, [1, 2]));
console.log(myFunc(add, [null]));
```